# Native module cannot be null on react-native-ios

Tags: ios, react-native, cross-platform, react-native-ios, mobile-application

When React-native application is running on ios simulator, build is showing successful but app is not launching and showing the given Error....."**Native module can not be null**"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFfDB.png)

please help me to find out the solution